# Function for querying a data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data.table called prices that has 3 columns: ticker, date and price.
I have run

```
setkey(prices,ticker,date)
```

If I do this from the code, it works

```
prices[list("MSFT",as.Date("2013-01-15")]
```

returning only the row for MSFT in 2013-01-15
However, if I write this function

```
getPrice <- function(ticker,date) {
  prices[list(ticker,date)]
}
```

it returns the whole data.table
I suspect that it has something to do with scoping in the i parameter, but I can't get it to work.
How do I query the data.table if I don't know the parameters in advance?

Comment: Without your data I cannot confirm, but using a toy example this works fine for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is the variable names in your function. Change them to be e.g. `x` and `y` (so that they are not the same as column names in your `data.table`) and everything will work. What you're doing now is constructing a `data.table` with all of `ticker` and `date` columns and then joining that, thus recovering the original data.

Another (more robust) option is to do smth like this in your function:

```
getPrice <- function(ticker,date) {
  tmp = list(ticker, date)
  prices[tmp]
}
```

See FAQs 2.12 and 2.13 for more on this - http://datatable.r-forge.r-project.org/datatable-faq.pdf

Comment: There has been mention of plans ([In the NEWS for version 1.8.2](https://r-forge.r-project.org/scm/viewvc.php/pkg/NEWS?view=markup&root=datatable)) to add ..() syntax  so that .() and ..() are analogous to the file system's ./ and ../; i.e., .() evaluates within the frame of DT and ..() in the parent scope.